# retrieve row based of indirect referencing

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble with a query. Based on the primary key, I have to use a foreign key in the same tuple/row to access another table where the foreign key is the primary key.

I have no idea how to approach this since I can't save the foreign key in a variable for example.

tldr a query to do this;

```
 1. Use user input to search for primary key
 2. Get requested row
 3. Use a column in that row to search for another table
 4. Get Second requested row
 5. Return all contents from the 2 rows requested.

SELECT * from table1 where table1.primaryKey = 'userInput'
UNION
SELECT * from table2, table1 where table1.foreignKey = table2.foreignKey;
```

This is what i have so far, but it doesn't work. But it illustrates my point.

Usually I do it with 2 queries, but i'd rather do it in one.

Comment: Use a JOIN between 2 queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `JOIN`s ?

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
  JOIN table1 
    ON table1.foreignKey = table2.foreignKey
WHERE table1.primaryKey = 'userInput'
```

Or, another way to do it would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.foreignKey = table2.foreignKey
      AND table1.primaryKey = 'userInput'
```